# SDF files with Gazebo plugin for ROS?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello All,
I recently learned that URDF is being deprecated, being substituted by SDF. I have in the past used spawn_models node to introduce new models in my Gazebo environment. How do I spawn SDF models? I tried using the 'Open' option in the Gazebo world GUI but it gives me the following error:

Error [parser.cc:566] XML Element[static], child of element[model] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[model] Error [parser.cc:557] Error reading element Error [parser.cc:340] Unable to parse sdf element[gazebo] Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed. Error [Server.cc:396] Unable to read sdf file[/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/objects/first_robotv3.sdf]

The SDF file I am trying to load is exactly from the tutorials found here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/build_robot/mobile_base

This should work with ROS as well right?

Please help. Thanks,
Ammar

EDIT: So after trying a few different configurations I observed that ROS has a gazebo node and a gazebo-1.0.2 node. Which one of these two supports SDF better? The default launch files I found in the simulator_gazebo stack were launching the "gazebo" node. When I try to launch the "gazebo-1.02" node I get the following error:
Error [SystemPaths.cc:262] cannot load file [sdf/gazebo.sdf]in GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH

I am really confused with which is a stable Gazebo version I should use.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/144/sdf-files-with-gazebo-plugin-for-ros?/) by [ammar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/75/ammar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

You can programmatically spawn an SDF model a couple ways:

1. Via a World or Model plugin:

- [Insert a Model from file](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.2.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html#a134428887e91b276a59cbd0a66196aa3)
- [Insert a Model from SDF Pointer](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.2.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html#aa9b38514c4c89672001c2913b10d37eb)
- [Insert a Model from SDF string](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.2.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html#a6b3dd3ee47725bbaf25f593e9f3ff9fb)

1. Via a msgs::Factory message on the "~/factory" topic.
2. Use the gzfactory command line tool.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoy.andy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/56/mcevoy.andy/) on 2012-11-06**:
is this only for v1.2? I get errors when trying to insert by the last two methods in point 1.  I followed the tutorial for v1.0. error = class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘InsertModelSDF’  and same thing for 'InsertModelString'

**Comment by [ammar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/75/ammar/) on 2012-11-06**:
I get errors in the last method as well: Error [SystemPaths.cc:262] cannot load file [sdf/gazebo.sdf]in GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH[/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo:]
ERROR: SDF parsing the xml failed

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-11-07**:
This is only for gazebo 1.2 and greater.

**Comment by [ammar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/75/ammar/) on 2012-11-08**:
Is there a gazebo 1.2 plugin for ROS?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-11-09**:
It is being worked on as we speak.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-01-14**:
These links all take me to the Gazebosim home page.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2016-02-15**:
Unfortunately the links in this answer have gone stale.